# Get coordinates of specified color of pixel on screen

Tags: c++

im making a game bot, and in some moments it must find (on the whole screen) a specified color of some pixel(without specified coordinates), and if it has founded it, bot has to print coordinates(x, y) of founded color.

I have a this example

```
int click_color = color;

HDC dc = GetDC(hWnd);
COLORREF click_col = GetPixel(dc, x, y);
ReleaseDC(NULL, dc);
```

it works fine, but it search for a color on a specified coordinates. But i need it the other way around, to search it on the whole screen and print coordinates of that color.

Can anyone help me?

Sorry for my broken English)

Comment: You need to write loops, to test the colour of each coordinate.

Comment: That is going to be a *very* slow function. "GetPixel" is already a slow function, and doing it for *every* pixel until you find a matching one is going to slow whatever you're doing to a crawl. Do you control the game? You'll need to output to some vbuffer or some other more efficient storage mechanism for this.

Comment: im not controlling a game , maybe there is a way to scan the screen for a correct pixel?

Comment: You need to grab the complete screen (1 frame) into a buffer and scan that. Have a read of [It’s easy to get data into the GPU, but harder to get it out](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20211223-00/?p=106050) to understand how slow calling  `GetPixel` is.  _"...If you absolutely must read from the screen DC, then do it in bulk with `Bit­Blt`...."_

Comment: What about GetDC Documentation saying "[in] hWnd A handle to the window whose DC is to be retrieved. If this value is NULL, GetDC retrieves the DC for the entire screen."

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any function that does that for you, so I believe your best shot would be to look through every pixel coordinate to check if the color corresponds. Obviously the GetPixel() funtion is too slow for that, so it would be best to capture the entirity of the screen and then analyze sequentially the pixels salved. When I need to do something like this I use this class after including Windows.h:

```
class screenshot
{
public:
    BYTE* lpbitmap;
    int horizontal;
    int vertical;
    COLORREF* pxMap;
private:
    HDC hScreenDC;
    HDC hMemoryDC;
    HBITMAP hBitmap;
    HBITMAP hOldBitmap;
    RECT desktop;
    const HWND hDesktop = GetDesktopWindow();
    BITMAPINFOHEADER bi;
    DWORD dwBmpSize;
    HANDLE hDIB;
    int x;
    int y;

    union color
    {
        int col;
        unsigned char abgr[4];
    };

public:
    screenshot()
    {
        hScreenDC = CreateDC(TEXT("DISPLAY"), NULL, NULL, NULL);
        hMemoryDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hScreenDC);

        x = GetDeviceCaps(hScreenDC, HORZRES);
        y = GetDeviceCaps(hScreenDC, VERTRES);


        GetWindowRect(hDesktop, &desktop);

        horizontal = desktop.right;
        vertical = desktop.bottom;

        bi.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
        bi.biWidth = horizontal;
        bi.biHeight = vertical;
        bi.biPlanes = 1;
        bi.biBitCount = 32;
        bi.biCompression = BI_RGB;
        bi.biSizeImage = 0;
        bi.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
        bi.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
        bi.biClrUsed = 0;
        bi.biClrImportant = 0;

        dwBmpSize = ((horizontal * bi.biBitCount + 31) / 32) * 4 * vertical;
        pxMap = new COLORREF[dwBmpSize];
        lpbitmap = new BYTE[dwBmpSize];


        hDIB = GlobalAlloc(GHND, dwBmpSize);

        hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hScreenDC, x, y);
    }

    void capture()
    {
        hOldBitmap = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hMemoryDC, hBitmap);


        BitBlt(hMemoryDC, 0, 0, horizontal, vertical, hScreenDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
        hBitmap = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hMemoryDC, hOldBitmap);


        GetDIBits(hMemoryDC, hBitmap, 0, (UINT)vertical, lpbitmap, (BITMAPINFO*)&bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
        GetObject(hBitmap, sizeof(lpbitmap), &lpbitmap);



        BYTE* img;
        for (int Y = 0; Y < vertical; Y++)
        {
            for (int X = 0; X < horizontal; X++)
            {
                img = lpbitmap + ((vertical - 1 - Y) * horizontal + X) * 4;
                pxMap[Y * horizontal + X] = RGB(img[2], img[1], img[0]);
            }
        }
    }

    ~screenshot()
    {
        GlobalFree(hDIB);
        DeleteDC(hMemoryDC);
        DeleteDC(hScreenDC);
    }

    COLORREF getPixel(int X, int Y)
    {
        //300 414

        return pxMap[Y * horizontal + X];
    }

    int getPixelRed(int X, int Y)
    {
        color col;
        col.col = pxMap[Y * horizontal + X];

        return col.abgr[0];
    }

    int getPixelGreen(int X, int Y)
    {
        color col;
        col.col = pxMap[Y * horizontal + X];

        return col.abgr[1];
    }

    int getPixelBlue(int X, int Y)
    {
        color col;
        col.col = pxMap[Y * horizontal + X];

        return col.abgr[2];
    }

};
```

Simply create an instance of it, capture a screenshot when you need to and go nuts analyzing the returned pixels.